# How can I add the product ID and name in stripe session Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

Im trying to make each session has it own product id based on my database products,
so this is my blade.php:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/../../../vendor/autoload.php');


\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_51xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],

    'line_items' => [[

      'price_data' => [
        'currency' => 'usd',
        'product_data' => [
          'name' => 'T-shirt',
        ],
        'unit_amount' => 2000,
      ],
      'quantity' => 1,

    ]],
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'success_url' => 'https://example.com/success',
    'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/cancel',
  ]);

?>
main>

    <div id="hey" class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

<div class="list-group" style="    margin: 100px 120px;">
    <h3>Account ID: #{{$product->id}}</h3>
    <h3>Account ID: #{{auth()->user()->name}}</h3>
  <input type="submit" id="submitBtn" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="button" autocomplete="off">
```

my route

```
Route::post('webhook/payment/succeeded', function (Request $request){
     if($request->type === "charge.succeeded"){
         try{
 Payment::create([
    'stripe_id' => $request->data['object']['id'],
     'amount' => $request->data['object']['amount'],
     'email' => $request->data['object']['billing_details']['email'],
     'name' => $request->data['object']['billing_details']['name'],
 ]);         } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
        return 'ok';
     }

});
```

all im trying to do is to add the product id inside the stripe session so I can delete that product when the payment is successful !, hope u will understand

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would want to delete the product when payment is successful? But to include the Product Id, you would want to either:

a. [Create a Stripe's Product beforehand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/create?lang=php) (also map it to your Product Database), then [include its Id](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=php#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data-product) when creating the Session.

b. [Put a metadata](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=php#create_checkout_session-metadata) when create a Session, include your Product Database's Id inside

Comment: Thank you sir , the reason why i want to delete it is because that's how my ecommerce website should work, but in the other the product id and price must be stored in other table for example order table

Comment: how can i map the stripe product id to the database